# difference between executing curl_close() once or frequently?

Tags: php, curl

When is it necessary to close curl connection and release resources consumed by it?

Why do I ask this question, well quite simply because I was told, that PHP garbage collector does all of this and sometimes there is no need to close DB connection or call the `__destruct` method to release resources.

Since, that moment I actually started to think about where do I need to call it then? At the moment I'm interested with that question since I writing a small library for curl and I'd like to understand when do I need to user `curl_close()` function.

Thank you all for discussion and explanation of it.

Comment: Be carefull on using this for changing data by curl (post, put etc), for it can reuse old data in the background, see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67266458/4699609

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as far as i understand it. The GC only cleans up resources that are no longer used/referenced. 
as whenever the curl variable fall out of scope, it'll be cleaned up. 
But that might only happen after the script has finished, or whenever the session is destroyed (depending on scope).

But to be on the safe side, just follow common sense.. close it when its no longer needed.

Comment: @Eugene - Don't you close your front door after going out? ;)

Comment: @Christian Sciberras Depends.

Comment: @Christian Sciberras - Great comparison.

Comment: If I had a door that closes automatically when I leave, then no - I would not close them manually.

Comment: @RoboRobok That's one hell of a door if it self-destructs your house; or should we say - 'a little housekeeping'.

Answer (score 12):

Results for 100 times `curl_exec`  (fetching url with cache avoiding):

## Executing in every loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; ++$i) {
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com/?rand=" . rand());
    curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);
}
```

> 8.5 seconds

## Executing only once :

```
$c = curl_init();
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; ++$i) {
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com/?rand=" . rand());
    curl_exec($c);
}
curl_close($c);
```

> 5.3 seconds

---

Decision: get used to always use optimal code in your tasks.
([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18046877/2377343))

Answer (score 1):

Depends. In my case since I was initializing curl instance in my custom `CurlClient` constructor

```
$this->ch = curl_init();
```

And then using same `$curlClient` object for multiple api calls, closing the instance

```
curl_close($this->ch);
```

would affect other API calls. Methods using the same object will not work, so I'm not closing it.