# Is it necessary to close a cURL connection?

Tags: php, curl

I created a wrapper function for cURL in PHP. Its simplified version looks like this:

```
function curl_get_contents($url, $try = 1) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '1');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, '1'); 

    // Execute the curl session
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($output === FALSE) {
        if ($try == 1) { //Try again
            return $this->curl_get_contents($url, 2);
        } else {
            return false;
        }    
    }        
}
```

As you can see, I force a retry of the function if it fails. Do I need to run `curl_close()`? Does PHP close all handles at the end of the script?

**UPDATE**

The linked question is extremely vague in its answer and doesn't support itself with data. I would really appreciate an answer based on perhaps a profiler that shows that PHP closes the connection immediately.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use cURLs function curl\_close?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849857/when-to-use-curls-function-curl-close)

Comment: @bansi, I came upon that answer before. However, it's rather vague, and doesn't point to documentation or any source.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No you don't - the garbage handler will take care of it for you, and you don't need to bother cleaning up memory yourself.

The precise answer is described in the manual entry ["*Resources*"](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php):

> **Freeing resources**
>
> Thanks to the reference-counting system introduced with PHP 4's Zend Engine, **a resource with no more references to it is detected automatically, and it is freed by the garbage collector**. For this reason, it is rarely necessary to free the memory manually.
>
> *Note: Persistent database links are an exception to this rule. They are not destroyed by the garbage collector. See the persistent connections section for more information.*

Answer (score 4):

No, it is really an optional step. However, it may be useful if you wish to re-use the same variable and initialize it with a different set of options.