# how to remove previously set request header referer field from curl handle?

Tags: php, curl, http-headers, libcurl

First I initialize curl handle:

```
$ch = curl_init();
```

Next I set the url and referer headers:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_REFERER,$referer);
```

And finally execute statement:

```
curl_exec($ch);
```

Now I can use another url without closing and reopening the handle, so:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$another_url);
```

And here headache begins, because I do not know how to disable referer header that would be send do server, of course I've tried to put `false` and `null` into CURLOPT_REFERER but it causes the referer field to be empty, that is a `Referer:` is still send to the server but with no value (is this even correct with http specs?).

Is there any option to remove header altogether without closing and reinstantiating curl handle ?

I'd like to avoid it because curl keeps a connection open for some time, if I would constantly close the handle while downloading from the same host it could take more time.

Comment: Do you have to remove the header entirely? Coudld you not just set it to be the same as the url you're requesting, or the url from the previous request?

Comment: Yes, I would like to. There could be servers that are very strict what should be in the referer. Until now I haven't encountered any, but I ask in advance.  The question is really that if such behavior is correct with regard to http specification ?

Comment: If a bug has been filled for it, could you show me link ?

Comment: Some good info @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787002/reusing-the-same-curl-handle-big-performance-increase

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can remove completely the referer field, or any other field normally handled by curl, by passing it without anything after ":" to `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Referer:"));
```

And it won't appear at all in the header.

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTHTTPHEADER

Answer (score 1):

The Referer header should be either the full URI or a URI relative to one requested:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#z14

It seems like a blank Referer header meets the spec, so you could just:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_REFERER,'');
```

The header will still appear, but it will be blank.