# Will PHP's CURL ever reuse connection for curl requests of different handles?

Tags: php, curl

- the discussing requests assumed to connect to same target host
- "handles" -> I meant the return from curl_init()
- Even document from the CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE option doesn't mention whether if not set that option, a connection reuse can happen across different curl handle or not.

I googled quite a lot, even CURL's official FAQ, but cannot find explicit answer.

Remark: related to question [Reusing the same curl handle. Big performance increase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787002/reusing-the-same-curl-handle-big-performance-increase/4736881#comment48516613_4736881), but the accepted answer didn't answer it explicitly, and no official reference.

Comment: Maybe this would answer your question: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#What_about_Keep_Alive_or_persist

`curl and libcurl have excellent support for persistent connections when transferring several files from the same server. Curl will attempt to reuse connections for all URLs specified on the same command line/config file, and libcurl will reuse connections for all transfers that are made using the same libcurl handle.`

Comment: @blubear  Thanks. Please make it an anwser.  So the answer is No I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this would answer your question:

[curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#What_about_Keep_Alive_or_persist](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#What_about_Keep_Alive_or_persist)

```
curl and libcurl have excellent support for persistent connections when
transferring several files from the same server. Curl will attempt to reuse
connections for all URLs specified on the same command line/config file, and 
libcurl will reuse connections for all transfers that are made using the same 
libcurl handle.
```

Comment: In other words, **"no"**.  From the above, they have to be the "same libcurl handle"