# PHP CURL - scrape seo urls when you only know the id

Tags: php, curl

I want to use curl to scrape multiple pages of an online shop. The problem that i have is that the urls are seo friendly - or something like that - and they look like this:

```
https://shopname.com/product-id-title-of-a-product.html
```

If i use the entire url it works and i'm able to get the data that i'm looking for but the only variable in that title that i know is the `ID`:

```
https://shopname.com/product-294
```

Is there a way to scrape that url in this case?

The url that only has the `ID` in it does `REDIRECT` to the full url.

And this is the code that i'm using:

```
$curl = curl_init();
$url = 'https://shopname.com/product-294';

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: Possibly no. ..

Comment: If that shop system does not deliver the content under that URL, and does not redirect to the full URL either … then no. Is this your shop?

Comment: Hey CBroe, the url does redirect me to the full url and no, and yes this is mine but i want to learn curl not query a db :D X_X

Comment: Hey Philipp, my probm is that if i insert a full url it works but with only the id in it doesn't but in the same time if i put that url with only the id in it in my browser and press enter it does redirect me X_X

Comment: @emma What does `curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE);` return, if you execute it after you executed your curl call?  302? If so, what does `curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL);` return afterwards?

Comment: @PhilippMaurer `curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE);` returns `301` and `curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL);` OMG it returns the actual url :O!!!!! THANK YOUUUUUU! <3 :D But now how is it ok to reexecute that curl method?

Comment: @emma It works as stated in the answer i just posted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Curl provides the option [`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

The documentation states:

> TRUE to follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part of the HTTP header (note this is recursive, PHP will follow as many "Location: " headers that it is sent, unless CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS is set).

Therefore it would be advisable to set `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS` aswell, for example to limit the execution to 1 redirection:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 1);
```

Like this you should be automatically be redirected to the original url without any further programming.

Comment: There are know problems with `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`, which' s solutions are documented in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2511410/8913537).

Comment: now it works, thank you sooooooo much for your time! Now i have only one more question, is it ok to use curl in a foreach if i have an array with 10 product id's that i want to scrap? :-s

Comment: @emma [This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18047230/8913537) should answer your question.

Comment: <3 Thank you again and again and again! :D

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to capture the response headers in the curl object, that should contain the redirect url within them, and then you can parse that out and do a second curl request to get the url you are after.
Try using an app like postman or insomnia to assist you in this process.

Comment: Hey noid, isn't there a way to write that code myself? #-o i mean could you please tell me a little bit more detaild about what i should look for? X_X

Comment: i have only done it in SOAP before, not Curl, so you would need to set something like this to get you started: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183178/can-php-curl-retrieve-response-headers-and-body-in-a-single-request

Comment: Phillipp Maurer has a much better answer than I have.

Comment: thank you for taking time to answer to my question! Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Having experienced the same thing myself with soap, I was sure that I could offer that experience as a possible solution, turns out Curl has it built in. :)